# Hololens falls asleep if moveless

Tags: c#, uwp, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

In my app I need to measure a camera data if the glasses are moving or not. I get the data with:

```
quaternions["x"] = Camera.main.transform.rotation.x;
quaternions["y"] = Camera.main.transform.rotation.y;
quaternions["z"] = Camera.main.transform.rotation.z;
quaternions["w"] = Camera.main.transform.rotation.w;
quaternions["tx"] = Camera.main.transform.position.x;
quaternions["ty"] = Camera.main.transform.position.y;
quaternions["tz"] = Camera.main.transform.position.z;
```

If I move the glasses, the app works fine. But if I leave the glasses on the table, then after 4 minutes the glasses disable display and the code returns last stored data. Even if the charge cable is plugged in. If I press enable button on the glasses, the display is on again and the data is also right.

Is there some possibility to prevent the glasses falling asleep?

Comment: I never used it on my own but did you try [Screen.sleepTimeout](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-sleepTimeout.html)?

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to comment of @Kay, the solution is adding the line:

```
Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;
```

NOTE: this solution works if you use [MixedRealityToolkit-Unity](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity) because it needs:

```
using UnityEngine;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the sleep settings using the Device Portal under System->Preference.

*When on battery, go to sleep after*

*When plugged in, go to sleep after*

[image]